# windows batch script for backup

Tags: command-line, batch-file, backup

I can't figure out how to write script that backpus only files that were created or modified previous day. So if I start script on 25.07 at 15:30, it backups files between 24.07 00:00 and 25.07 00:00.
If it is possible preffered way is by using robocopy. I know for /maxage -1 switch but it works for files that are 1 day old counting form the time script was started (problem is because it includes files from current day also).

```
set source="C:\Folder1"
set destination="F:\Folder2"
robocopy %source% %destination% /z /MAXAGE: -1
```

Comment: not meant for SO . but why don't you use some backup tool http://www.idrive.com/?uid=O2V7U0H4B4

Comment: @GauravShah, why is it not meant for SO? @@ValentQ, please post your original script so that there's something to work with.

Comment: if you see the unedited question it didn't show any code so I assumed that he just wants to make automated backups...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Robocopy gives you two options for specifying dates (for maxage, minage, maxlad, minlad) - either relative (n<1900) or fixed dates (otherwise, treated as yyyymmdd). [Full syntax here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28WS.10%29.aspx). 

You want to include files created or accessed on given date so you have to use min/max lad (last access date) and fixed dates, so let's specify your criteria using robocopy syntax:

1. Exclude files unused since yesterday: use /maxlad (today_date - 1 day)

2. Exclude files used today: use /minlad (today_date)

Put those together:
 `robocopy source_dir destination_dir  file_spec /maxlad:%today_minus_1%  /minlad:%today%`

`today` and `today_minus_1` vars must be dates in yyyymmdd format (eg.20120710) - how to get them? Well, if you're constrained to pure batch you would have to find scripts to do the math for you, there are some available (eg. [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/datetime.php)) or write it yourself. 

If you can use powershell it's pretty simple: 
`for /f %y in ('powershell get-date ^(get-date^).adddays^(-1^) -uformat %Y%m%d') do set today_minus_1=%y` gets you first, and 

`for /f %t in ('powershell get-date -uformat %Y%m%d') do set today=%t` second variable.

So to summarize: set your date vars and then run robocopy (using them in excludes). It's worth to use `/L` option when checking if it works properly, as actual copy will re-set access timestamps on your files!

All vars and commands given as if executed directly from cmd line. If used in batch you will need to add some `%` (and probably wise to use setlocal)

Note: version I use (XP010) does **not** allow to use negative numbers or space as in your example